# Global variable / state ASP.NET MVC 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have `ITaskRepository` that work with storage.
TaskRepository(XML Storage) and TaskRepository(SQL Storage) different implementations of `ITaskRepository`. I want in View make selector with two options: XML / SQL. User select one of this option and whole application switches to selected storage.

I create dynamic dependency injection, but I don't know where I can save value - XML/SQL.

You have may any ideas? Thank you!

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<ITaskRepository>(provider =>
{
    string typeStorage = "sql"; // neccesary get from another place

    switch (typeStorage)
    {
        case "sql":
            {
                return provider.GetService<MicrosoftSQLServerDb.Repositories.TaskRepository>();
            }
        case "xml":
            {
                return provider.GetService<StorageXml.Repositories.TaskRepository>();
            }
        default:
            {
                return provider.GetService<MicrosoftSQLServerDb.Repositories.TaskRepository>();
            }
            
    }
});
```

Comment: The answer is: `appsettings.json`. You can read more about configuration [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: @Neistow, Ok, thank you! I'll read about it. One more question:  save and rewriting dynamic "variables" there it's good practice?)

Comment: This configuration can be dynamic if it is intended to and it's totally fine. For dynamic configuration you can use something that's called [Options Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-6.0)